# PHP JSON Decoding String Issue/ Facebook messenger

Tags: php, json, facebook, api, messenger

I have a JSON that looks like this, and I used json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true); to turn it into an array

```
{
"object": "page",
"entry": [
    {
        "id": "",
        "time":,
        "messaging": [
            {
                "sender": {
                    "id": ""
                },
                "recipient": {
                    "id": ""
                },
                "timestamp":,
                "message": {
                    "mid": "",
                    "seq": "",
                    "text": "STORE, POSTAL CODE"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

After the JSON was decoded I wanted to grab the text portion of the JSON, so i did

```
$message = ($post['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']
$query = explode(',', $message);
```

I then used $query[0], and $query[1] in some SQL queries.

For some reason, when I hardcode $message to some text like $message = 'store, postal'; it'll work but not when I use explode.

FYI, this json is coming from Facebook as I'm using the messenger api.

Comment: did you try printing what you get in $post['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'] first? if not then I suggest first check it once because explode will never fail for sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that $post['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']
   gives you "STORE, POSTAL CODE".
2. As I see json contains uppercase strings and your example is lowercase. Maybe this is important in your code further.

Comment: I've looked at what the $post returns and it is what is expected, the "STORE, POSTAL CODE" is just meant as a placeholder, but what should really be expected is like, 'somestore, postalcode' in lower cases, I also have some text cleaning that I do after.

Furthermore, I've tested it when hardcoding $message, and everything works as I intended, its just when I split it with the incoming text that things mess up.